# Remote Server Administration Tool

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

[image: screenshot]

i am trying to install RSAT ,BUT there is error ,"Installer encountered an error 0x8007052e" The username and password is incorrect.HOW to fix this to install RSAT

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you Googled the message? Is that MSU even the RSAT installer for Windows 8....?

Comment: yeah i tried for the message but now about MSU.and i try to find installer for 8.1 but now i am downloading  then i will inform you,

Answer (score 1):

The shown screenshot indicates that you are trying to install the RSAT for Windows 7 (hence the 6.1).

The proper installer for Windows 8 is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972

And the proper installer for Windows 8.1 is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296

The RSAT packages are specific to the version of Windows you are running.  Also, I should add that only Professional or higher version of Windows can run the RSAT.

Comment: i install windows 8.1

Comment: but why it showing the username name and password is incorrect?what is the reason

Comment: i tried these version for 8.1 but still same error.

Comment: Are you an administrator of the computer? if not, you cannot install the RSAT.

Comment: i tried in in both mode as a simple user and as a admin both cause the same issue

Comment: Are all other Windows Updates installed?  what happens if you try to a different stand-alone update?

Comment: yes all are installed. when i tried a different update it give the same error